# Get touch position google maps iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, google-maps-sdk-ios

GMSMapView creates a UIView that handles gestures recognizer, I want  detect where in the UIView the user is giving a touch, I can get the marker position (relative to map coordinates) but I want the current position of the touch on the view. Any ideas?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I got the question right, you want to calculate CGPoint of touch location in Map's UIView?

So, you have a CLLocationCoordinate2D you got from Delegate's method, you can get it's position by calling on GMSProjection object on you GMSMapview like:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
 CGPoint locationInView = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:coordinate]; // capitalize the V
}
```

and the locationInView will be the desired location. So, the GMSProjection's method

```
- (CGPoint)pointForCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
```

gives you point of touch in Map's view.

Hope it helps :)